# PL/SQL API Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I wonder if there is a official documentation/API for the different functions which is defined in Oracle? I find it rather hard to remember functions when I stumble upon them and then bookmark the website for later reference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Documentation for Oracle versions 8.1.7 and on is available at http://tahiti.oracle.com

For every version, there is a [PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/toc.htm) manual that should provide information about all the supplied packages (occasionally, you'll find a package that is associated with a specialized function documented in the specialized manual rather than in the packages & types reference, but that's pretty rare).  The SQL Reference also has a chapter on [functions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions.htm#i1482196) that lists the supplied functions.